# moveit benchmark log, where is it?

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am trying to run some benchmarks with moveit and the rviz plugin, following this tutorial: http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Benchmarking

The benchmark seems to run without problems, except that I am not able to find the log file to see the results.

In the tutorial it is stated this, about the configuration file parameters:

> output (optional) Location for saving
> computed data in *.log format. "1.log"
> will automatically be appended to the
> file name. The default output location
> is in in your ~/.ros folder.

but I can't find the log file in that folder... Maybe it's a bug? Where do I have to search for it?

Thank you in advance!

kir

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69397/moveit-benchmark-log,-where-is-it?/) by [kir](https://answers.ros.org/users/5291/kir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-04**:
It says optional. Did you enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The logs are written in a hidden folder under your home folder:

```
ls $HOME/.ros/log
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0